# DB2 error : SQL0204N "SQL160215110205990" is an undefined name

Tags: sql, db2, sql-function

I have following indexes/unique constraints in my table.

```
 INDNAME               COLNAMES  
 SQL160215110206240    +ID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 SQL160215110206360    +ENTITY_TYPE+TENANT_ID+ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE+ENTITY_NAME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 SQL160215145445420    +ENTITY_TYPE+TENANT_ID+ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE+ENTITY_NAME+PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID
```

Now I run following code segment on my darabase.

```
BEGIN 
 DECLARE v_rcount VARCHAR(128);
 DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(200); 
 select INDNAME into v_rcount from SYSCAT.INDEXES WHERE TABNAME='IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY' AND         COLNAMES='+ENTITY_TYPE+TENANT_ID+ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE+ENTITY_NAME';  
 SET STMT = 'ALTER TABLE IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY DROP CONSTRAINT ' ||  v_rcount; 
 PREPARE S1 FROM STMT; 
 EXECUTE S1;
END
```

When I run it for the 1st time, I am getting following response.

```
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

But when I list the indexes of the table, I am still seeing all 3 indexes as before.

And also when I run the same code segment again, I am getting following error.

```
SQL0204N  "SQL160215110206360" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
```

Not only this index, if I try to drop any other index in the same database, I am getting the same error. What is the reason for this? How can I solve this?

Comment: What I want to do is remove the constraint for +ENTITY_TYPE+TENANT_ID+ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE+ENTITY_NAME columns, If the constraint has been removed, why I can still see it in SYSCAT.INDEXES table? Also why I can't drop any other constraints?

Comment: Is the table name unique within the database or are there multiple schemas having the same table? This is often in multi-tenant systems.

Comment: Yes, there are some other databases with same tables.

Comment: Actually table name is unique within the database, but I have several databases with the same set of tables.

Comment: If you are searching for that specific constraint within a single DB2 database, only one object should come back. If you have multiple sets of tables organized by schema in a DB2 database, multiple will come back and you need to be more precise in qualifying the objects. Please clarify that you really are not talking about schemas.

Comment: You can find the schema of my database at https://gist.github.com/cdwijayarathna/576c932fbf9c6b3a5ce9, currently I have two databases (test3 and test5) and both databases has the same set of tables in above schema, I have connected to databse 'test3' by 'db2 connect to test3' and run all commands from there. When select constraints from SYSCAT.INDEXES after connecting to test2, I am only getting constraints of that database

Comment: Constraint and index are different objects. I don't think dropping a constraint will drop the underlying index in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for this issue is, I am getting the name from SYSCAT.INDEXES. So there it is returning the name of INDEX. Even though a INDEX is created to each unique constraint, name of index can be different from name of Constraint. So here I have dropped the constraint and then I have checked the index table if it has removed. That's the reason why I can see the same index name still after removing the constraint.

Also every index name in SYSCAT.INDEXES will not refer to a constraint. So everytime I run DROP CONSTRAINT with a name from SYSCAT.INDEXES will not return success.

Answer (score 0):

IBM DB2 behaves little bit differently compared to other well known databases when comes to constraints and indexes. So let me explain the solution for your problem in detail.

You have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY (
            ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            ENTITY_TYPE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            ENTITY_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            ENTITY_VALUE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (ID),
            UNIQUE (ENTITY_TYPE, TENANT_ID, ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE, ENTITY_NAME),
            UNIQUE (PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, ENTITY_VALUE),
            FOREIGN KEY (PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID) REFERENCES IDP_PROVISIONING_CONFIG(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
/
```

It has a primary key and two unique constraints. The DB2 will automatically create indexes for these three constraints.

The problem is, we have not defined the constraints as named constraints. Therefore we have to take an extra effort to find out the names of the indexes and the constraints which are auto generated by DB2.

These are the two unique constraints that we have in the table.

```
        UNIQUE (ENTITY_TYPE, TENANT_ID, ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE, ENTITY_NAME),
        UNIQUE (PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, ENTITY_VALUE)
```

You can find the auto generated names for the unique constraints by running the following query. the constraintyp='U' for unique constraints and it is 'P' for primary keys.


**db2 "select NAME from sysibm.systabconst where tbname='IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY' and constraintyp='U'"**

```
NAME                                                                                                                           
--------
SQL160219074557840                                                                                                             
SQL160219074557920
```

Above is the result I got. You will get different values in your database as these are random generated.

You can run the following query to see the indexes created for the IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY' table.


**db2 "SELECT NAME, COLNAMES FROM SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES WHERE TBNAME='IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY'"**

```
NAME                            COLNAMES
SQL160219074557290                +ID 
SQL160219074557790                +PROVISIONING_CONFIG_ID+ENTITY_TYPE+ENTITY_VALUE
SQL160219074557860                +ENTITY_TYPE+TENANT_ID+ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE+ENTITY_NAME
```

Now we know the constraint names for the two unique constraints and the index names for the IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY table.

You can find the particular index you need to drop by adding a where clause for the above query as below.


**db2 "SELECT NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES WHERE TBNAME='IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY' and COLNAMES='+ENTITY_TYPE+TENANT_ID+ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE+ENTITY_NAME'"**

```
NAME                                                  
----------
SQL160219074557860
```

In IBM DB2, you cannot drop an index which is generated for a constraint (primary key or unique) directly. For that, you need to drop the constraint which will drop the index also.

But the problem is we do not know what is the name of the unique constraint that is associated with the index "+ENTITY_TYPE+TENANT_ID+ENTITY_LOCAL_USERSTORE+ENTITY_NAME". We already know that the index name we need to drop is SQL160219074557860.

You can find it out which constraint is associated with which index by running the following query.


**db2 "select CONSTNAME, BNAME from SYSCAT.CONSTDEP where TABNAME = 'IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY'"**

```
CONSTNAME                  BNAME
SQL160219074557790      SQL160219074557290
SQL160219074557840      SQL160219074557790
SQL160219074557920      SQL160219074557860
```

Based on the results, you can get to know the name of the constraint.
So the constraint name associated with the index name "SQL160219074557860" is "SQL160219074557920".

So since we know the constraint name now, we can drop the unique constraint.


**db2 "ALTER TABLE IDP_PROVISIONING_ENTITY DROP UNIQUE SQL160219074557920"**

This will drop the constraint as well as the index created for the constraint.

Comment: I have written the following blog post explaining this. You can refer that to understand this scenario easily. 

http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/02/ibm-db2-dropping-indexes-created-for.html